# Why Servlet is unavailable after 3rd deployment in jboss 4.2.0

Tags: servlets, jboss, hotdeploy

I am working in a struts-hibernate application. I have seen a error on 3rd time deployment of application in jboss4.2.0. When i deployed it for first time, it runs. Even in 2nd time deployment, it works. But, in 3rd time deployment, it shows an error "Servlet is unavailable".
Why it fails in 3rd time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PermGenSpace could be too small? Try increasing this value. Do you get any messages in the JBoss log?